# Get "ActionView::MissingTemplate" error, when I post json to rails controller from angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I use angularjs in my new ruby on rails project. I create my view with angularjs and back end server with ruby on rails.

Now, I have a form in angular part, when user complete the form and click on send, I post a json like below to server:

```
    $scope.jsonList = {
        "form1": {name:"John",lastName:"Smart"},
        "form2": {job:"student",age:"18"}
    };
```

I post this json to a `test` action in rails controller. I put javascript (angularjs) and server side code below:

angularController:

```
   //Services
   .factory('Test', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/test.json', {}, {
            create: { method: 'post'}
        });
    })
    //Angular Controller
   $scope.testResponse = Test.create(angular.toJson($scope.jsonList));
```

and `routes.rb`:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
      scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: :true) do
        match '/test',to:'dropdowns#test', via: 'post'
      end
  end
```

and `dropdownsController`:

```
class Api::V1::DropdownsController < Api::V1::BaseController
   def test

   end
end
```

I do all this, but when I post json to rails server, I recieve json, but I get below error:

```
Started POST "/api/test.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-22 17:11:10 +0330
Processing by Api::V1::DropdownsController#test as JSON
  Parameters: {"form1"=>{"name"=>"John", "lastName"=>"Smart"}, "form2"=>{"job"=>"student", "age"=>"18"}, "dropdown"=>{"form1"=>{"name"=>"John", "lastName"=>"Smart"}, "form2"=>{"job"=>"student", "age"=>"18"}}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template api/v1/dropdowns/test, api/v1/base/test with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/mgh/Documents/Maliat/sama/app/views"
):
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:124:in `find'
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in `find_template'
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:41:in `determine_template'
```

**I can do any thing with json when I recieve in rails controller (like parse and puts on console and save in database with other controller), but at the end of controller, I get above error and I cannot post any response to angular part. Where is the problem?**

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not explicitly rendering anything in the `test` method so rails is looking for a template to send back as a response.  However, you don't have a json template in your `api/v1/dropdowns/` folder (I think it will look for a file called `test.json` in your case).

You can solve this by either sending back a response explicitly, (check out this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more about rendering a response.

```
def test
   render plain: "This is the response from 'test' method in DropDownsController"
end
```

or you want to return json of a model

```
def test
   render json: @product
end
```

OR

You can put a template in your `api/v1/dropdowns/` folder and rails will serve that instead.  But the overall point is you need to send back a response.

For example:
`api/v1/dropdowns/test.json.erb`

```
{
    "name" : "my name is greg or something"
}
```